How to add multicast route in UE?
I'm considering implementing D2D multicast routing emulation between UEs (NRCars) based on the example found at http://simu5g.org/emulation_openness.html.
However, when HostA sends a packet, it's supposed to be routed as a D2D multicast to another UE within the simulation. But it seems the multicast routing table is empty, resulting in the packet being dropped.
Unfortunately, It appears that dynamic modules like NRCar cannot modify the multicast routing table using Ipv4NetworkConfigurator.
dynamic modules can only work with HostAutoConfigurator. While normal routing tables can be modified using Routing Files (.mrt), this method doesn't apply to multicast routing tables.
Is there a way to modify the multicast routing table?
